# How can I duplicate every row in an excel file using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have an excel file with rows like this:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5
anotherCol1 | anotherCol2 | anotherCol3 | anotherCol4 | anotherCol5
```

and I need to duplicate every row so that it looks like this:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5
anotherCol1 | anotherCol2 | anotherCol3 | anotherCol4 | anotherCol5
anotherCol1 | anotherCol2 | anotherCol3 | anotherCol4 | anotherCol5
```

This is what I have so far and the excel file is an .XLS file not an .XLSX file so I can't use `openpyxl` unless there is someway around that.

This is what I have so far:

```
    def DuplicateEachRow(self):
        import pandas as pd
        import pathlib
        full_path = str(pathlib.Path().absolute()) + '\\' + new_loc
        df = pd.read_excel(full_path, header=None, sheet_name=None)

        # engine can be openpyxl if we need .xlsx ext
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(new_loc, engine='xlwt') 
        for key in df:
            sheet = df[key]
            sheet.to_excel(writer, key, index=False, header=False)
            print(sheet)
        # writer.save()
```

How can I use the 'sheet' which is the `dataframe` to duplicate each row?

EDIT: I tried this as well...

```
    def DuplicateEachRow(self):
        import pandas as pd
        import pathlib
        full_path = str(pathlib.Path().absolute()) + '\\' + new_loc

        df = pd.read_excel(full_path, header=None, sheet_name='GTL | GWL Disclosures')
        print(df)

        # duplicate the rows:
        dup_df = pd.concat([df, df], ignore_index=True)

        # using openpyxl
        with pd.ExcelWriter('path_to_file.xlsx') as writer:
            dup_df.to_excel(writer)
```

but this only writes back out to one sheet instead of the original workbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to duplicate the rows in a dataframe is to concatenate the dataframe with itself:

```
pd.concat([df, df])
```

and if you want to reset the index

```
pd.concat([df, df], ignore_index=True)
```

For your example:

```
def DuplicateEachRow(self):
        import pandas as pd
        import pathlib
        full_path = str(pathlib.Path().absolute()) + '\\' + new_loc

        ##This should give you the dataframe for which you want to   duplicate the rows 
        ##You should check this is the case, I don't have your .xls file. 
        ##Sometimes the sheet name is "Sheet1" and not None)
        df = pd.read_excel(full_path, header=None, sheet_name=None)
        
        #duplicate the rows:
        dup_df = pd.concat([df, df], ignore_index=True)  
         
        #using openpyxl
        with pd.ExcelWriter('path_to_file.xlsx') as writer:
             dup_df.to_excel(writer)
```

EDIT: new version that inserts each duplicated row just after the original row and appends a new sheet to same file

```
def DuplicateEachRow():
    import pandas as pd
    import pathlib
    full_path = str(pathlib.Path().absolute()) + '\\' + new_loc

    df = pd.read_excel(full_path, header=None, sheet_name='GTL | GWL Disclosures')
    print(df)

    # duplicate the rows:
    # keep the index, so you can sort the rows after
    dup_df = pd.concat([df, df])
    #sort the rows by the index so you have the duplicate one just after the initial one
    dup_df.sort_index(inplace=True)

    # using openpyxl
    #open the file in append mode 
    with pd.ExcelWriter(new_loc, mode='a') as writer:
        #use a new name for the new sheet
        #don't save the header (dataframe columns names) and index (dataframe row names) in the new sheet  
        dup_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet3', header=None, index=None)
```

Comment: How do I use that in my example?

Comment: I got this error when I run it `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'dict'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`

Comment: Actually I got it by changing sheet name but the file looks formatted different now

Comment: How does the df look like?

Comment: when i print `df` it correctly shows my excel. Ill update my question with the changes I made to your code

Comment: Where do you want to write it? In the same excel file from where you took the initial data? If so, just use the same file name.

Comment: when i do that and I go back and look at my file, the duplicates aren't there

Comment: I added a new question that will explain better if you can please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64054877/how-to-save-excel-sheet-to-the-original-workbook

Comment: actually it looks like this just appends all existing rows to the end. I need rows to be inserted.

Comment: I edit this answer and add the answer to your other question also. Hope this helps, and please don't forget to accept or upvote the answer if it helps.

Comment: I sure will! About to test out your solution in like 30 minutes, based on what you said though, if it works it should be exactly what I need. Thank you. I’ll be sure to let you know/upvote if it works

Comment: Haven't been able to test it yet. My file is an .xls file so first I need to convert it to .xlsx file for your code to work so ill try that now

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

This option will open the workbook based on index number, reads in data, doubles the rows, then rewrites the doubled rows to the sheet you've called and avoids using openpyxl if you can't use it. As far as `iloc` not being found I'm not sure why that is occurring, it is a component of the pandas package. Perhaps try reinstalling pandas to the latest version but I'm having success on my end.

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy
import pandas as pd 


df = pd.read_excel('yourxls.xls',sheet_name='your_sheet',header=None) 
df_new = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(len(df)):
    df_new = df_new.append(df.iloc[i])
    df_new = df_new.append(df.iloc[i])

rb = open_workbook("yourxls.xls")
wb = copy(rb)
s = wb.get_sheet(1) #get sheet by index number

num_col = len(df_new.columns)
num_row = len(df_new)

df_vals = df_new.values

for i in range(num_row):
    for j in range(num_col):
        s.write(i,j, df_vals[i,j])

wb.save('yourxls.xls')
```

I did have to pip install `'xlrd'` and `'xlwt'` to work with the `.xls` format

Comment: How can I do this to one particular sheet?

Comment: And it says iloc is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to do this directly using openpyxl: work from the bottom of the sheet, insert a row and copy the values from the row above it.